# Artillery load testing not working with socket.io engine

Tags: socket.io, artillery

I'm testing my video-chat app with artillery load testing, when I run a script file with only get request it works, but as soon I use `socketio` as engine it shows error.

```
    config:
      target: "http://localhost:4200"
     
      phases:
        - duration: 30
          arrivalRate: 2
     
    scenarios:
      - engine: socketio
        flow:
          - get:
              url: "/room/68820603-4836-47d2-a2fd-eceedc07c607"
```

this is my script file, and result is this one

`Warning: multiple batches of metrics for period 1690469410000 2023-07-27T14:50:10.000Z
All VUs finished. Total time: 31 seconds

---

### Summary report @ 16:50:16(+0200)

errors.Error: xhr poll error: .................................................. 60
vusers.created: ................................................................ 60
vusers.created_by_name.0: ...................................................... 60
vusers.failed: ................................................................. 60`

Can anyone help me,  I searched online but not much is found.

I searched online for answers, but no luck